# 「この広告を報告」がエンコードされた状態で表示されている

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

SOja の右側サイドバーに出てきた広告の下に書かれている文字列が、[文字実体参照](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%8F%82%E7%85%A7)がデコードされずにそのまま出てきたように表示されているのを見つけました。

> [image: 表示されている箇所のスクリーンショット]

ここには `&#x3053;&#x306E;&#x5E83;&#x544A;&#x3092;&#x5831;&#x544A;` と書かれていて、これを文字実体参照としてデコードすると「この広告を報告」になります。この string だと思われます: https://ja.traducir.win/strings/13323

システム側のエンコードタイミングかどこかに不具合がありそうなので調査をお願いしたいです。

---

Edit: MSE にも投稿しました [Multibyte characters for "Report this ad" string are broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383153/341401)

Comment: ポルトガル語版とロシア語版でも起きていますね。特にロシア語版は文字列が長くなり完全にはみ出ているので、さすがに修正されそうです。

Comment: 日本語版と同様ポルトガル語版もうまく修正されましたが、ロシア語版の "Report this ad" リンクは[一時的に無効](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383517/the-page-on-the-site-ru-stackoverflow-com-is-going-crazy#comment1279298_383517)にされたようです。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

問題が修正され、「この広告を報告」と表示されるようになりました。

[image: decoded]